# ¿Como vincular childData con el texto de un script en una solicitud de firebase?

Tags: html, firebase

Estoy intentando obtener los datos desde firebase,  a un html simple pero no me cargan los datos al solicitarlos
quiero que al ingresar un texto en el input "numero" este se vincule con childData['numero'] y me lo publique en p"data"
Alguien sabe como hacerlo funcionar?

```
<input id="numero" type="text" value="">
<p id = "data"></p>

var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
var childData = childSnapshot.val();
document.getElementById("data").value = childData['numero'];
```